# C# Windows Service doesn't seem to like privatePath

Tags: c#, windows-services

I wrote a C# Windows Service to handle task scheduling for our application.  I'm trying to move the "business rules" assemblies into a bin subdirectory of the scheduling application to make it easier for us to do updates (stop service, delete all files in bin folder, replace with new ones, start service).

I added

```
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <probing privatePath="bin;"/>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

to the service's app config and it works fine if the service is run as a console application.  Problem is when the service is run as a windows service it doesn't work.  It appears that when windows runs the service the app config file gets read properly but then the service is executed as if it was in c:\windows\system32 and not the actually EXE location and that gums up the works.

We've got a lot of assemblies so I really don't want to use the GAC or `<codeBase>`.  Is it possible to have the EXE change it's base directory back to where it should be when it's run as a service?

Comment: Does it work if you put the DLLs in the same folder as the EXE?  Then the codebase is good.  I don't see the `<configuration>` element, is it there?  Use fuslogvw.exe to troubleshoot resolution problems.

Comment: Yes, everything works fine when the EXE is run as a service and the assemblies are in the same folder as the EXE.  Yes, the config file has <configuration> (actual config much longer which is why I didn't post the whole thing).  I'll give fuslogvw.exe a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was wrong.  privatePath works fine even from a windows service.  Issue was I had added the `<runtime>` section to the top of the app.config which throws an error because `<configSections>` is not the first item in the file.  However the service still signaled that it started fine (something we have to fix) and the log file used for start up errors was being written to a directory other than the one with the EXE (something ELSE we have to fix) once I moved the `<runtime>` block to its proper place in the app.config everything worked perfectly.

Kudos to the comment for the fuslogvw.exe, I'd give the answer to you if I could.  It allowed me to see that the privatePath was being followed and that the error was elsewhere.

Comment: Your answer reassured me I could get this to work with my TopShelf service. In my case I had copy and pasted an incorrect xmlns from somewhere on the net. Thanks!

Comment: @c17r Where is the "proper place"?

Comment: @David if your config file has a <configSections> block, it needs to be first block in the file. I had the <runtime> block first. I just moved it to be after <configSections>

Comment: @c17r <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections></configSections>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas=microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <probing privatePath="bin" />
    </assemblyBinding>
    
  </runtime>Is not working for me.

Comment: @David if you don't have any custom configuration settings then you don't need to have `<configSections />` in there. I don't know if it was a copy/paste error but your config doesn't have a `</configuration>` tag. Beyond that, I'm not sure what you're problem could be, everything looks fine. If you are still having issues, try watching things with `fuslogvw.exe`. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use a fully qualified path.  You are right about it looking for the bin in system32 if you don't fully qualify it when it is running as a service.

Comment: I didn't think you could do a fully qualified path with privatePath, that it had to be a subdirectory of the EXE's directory.  Or is my knowledge outdated?